# Regular expression not matching pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm using a regular expression

```
/[A-Za-z]{3}(P|p){1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/
```

For matching pattern :

```
3 alphabets A to Z
1 letter to be exactly P
1 letter A to Z
4 digits
1 letter A to Z
```

Its working for all scenarios but failing in one case where we enter text as

```
awdejhjhpr5467y
```

you can consider testing it [HERE](https://regex101.com/)

Its accepting more than 3 alphabets in starting. Whats lacking in expression Can someone please help !.

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z]{3}(P|p){1}[A-Za-z]{1}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/`

Comment: I'm assuming this is a stand-alone string such that there are no adjacent non-white-space characters to the left of your expected pattern?

Comment: [`/^[a-z]{3}p[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/xG6lP8/2)

Comment: Your "failed" match is just not matching on the entire string as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/cI8zO9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `^` in your regex, otherwise which will not assert match from the beginning of the string. Also there is no need of `{1}` and you can reduce the regex by adding `i` flag which ignore the case

```
/^[a-z]{3}p[a-z]\d{4}[a-z]$/i
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/jS8lB4/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @VinodLouis You also forgot that there is `i` flag and `{1}` is not required.